# Minimum function for the order topology is continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y$ be an ordered topological space
(see definition below) and $f,g: X\to Y$ be continuous maps. Prove
that:
The map $h: X\to Y$ defined by $$h(x)=\min\{f(x),g(x)\}$$ is continuous on $X$.

PS: Assume $(X,\leq)$ is the set with linear order (if $x,y$ in $X$ then $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x$). Denote $\mathbb{B}$ is a family of subsets of $X$ having one of $3$ following forms:

1. $\{x\in X|a<x<b\}$, $a,b\in X, a<b$.
2. $\{x\in X|x<a\}$, $a\in X$.
3. $\{x\in X|a<x\}$, $a\in X$.

I already proved some following results:
a) $Y$ is the Hausdorff space.
b) $A=\{(y_1,y_2)\in Y\times Y:y_1<y_2\}$ is open in product topology $Y\times Y$.
c) $B=\{x\in X:f(x)\leq g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.
Still, I don't know how to prove $h$ is continous. Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First show that the map $(y_1, y_2)\mapsto \min(y_1, y_2)$ is continuous.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I show that map is continuous? I have no idea how to proceed

Comment: Yeah of course. Order topology is generated by open rays, so you need to show that $$\{(y_1, y_2) : \min(y_1, y_2) < z\}$$ and $$\{(y_1, y_2) : z < \min(y_1, y_2)\}$$ are open. Try to write those sets differently using properties of $\min$

Answer (score 0):

To prove this first consider the minimum function $s:(y_1, y_2)\mapsto \min(y_1, y_2)$, which is a function from $Y^2$ to $Y$. Open rays $$(-, z) = \{y\in Y : y < z\}\text{ and }(z, -) = \{y\in Y : z<y\}$$ form a subbasis for the topology of $Y$, so to prove that $s$ is continuous we just need to show that the preimages of open rays are open.

Note that \begin{align*}  s^{-1}[\{y\in Y : y < z\}] & = \{(y_1, y_2)\in Y^2 : \min(y_1, y_2) < z\} \\ &=\{(y_1, y_2)\in Y^2 : y_1 < z \text{ or }y_2 < z\} \\ &= \{(y_1, y_2)\in Y^2: y_1 < z\} \cup \{(y_1, y_2)\in Y^2 : y_2 < z\} \\ &= (-, z)\times Y \cup Y\times (-, z)\end{align*} is open as a union of two open sets. The sets $(-, z)\times Y$ and $Y\times (-, z)$ are open in $Y^2$ by definition of product topology.

Similarly, \begin{align*}  s^{-1}[\{y\in Y : z < y\}] & = \{(y_1, y_2)\in Y^2 : z <\min(y_1, y_2)\}\\ &= \{(y_1, y_2)\in Y^2 : z < y_1\text{ and }z < y_2\} \\ &= (z, -)\times (z, -) \end{align*} which again is open by definition of product topology.

Now, the function $h(x) = \min(f(x), g(x))$, $h:X\to Y$ is a composition of functions $x\mapsto (f(x), g(x))$ from $X$ to $Y^2$, and $s:Y^2\to Y$. The function $s$ is continuous by the discussion above, and the function $x\mapsto (f(x), g(x))$ is continuous by properties of product topology, from continuity of $f$ and $g$.